# Can One Domain Have Multiple Cookies?

Tags: http, cookies

Can one domain generate multiple cookies on visitor's web browser?
If so, when user vists the website, which cookies will be delivered to server? And why would a website generate multiple cookies?

I checked my Google Chrome Browser's Cookies settings, found that there are multiple cookies of nytimes.com.

If server wants to store multiple key/value pairs in cookies, can't they be stored in the same cookies?

[image: multiple cookies]

[image: cookies-1]

[image: cookies-2]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes :)

I would speculate that the cookies were created by separate components of the website, which were created by separate teams of developers. We, of all people, should realize that this is often the case when we need to get some development done but do not have time to wait for collaboration or for another team to develop a necessary layer for us.

From wikipedia:

> Relevant count of maximum stored cookies per domain for the major browsers are:
>
> - Firefox 3.0: 50
> - Opera 9: 30
> - Internet Explorer 7: 50

Answer (score 11):

> Can one domain generate multiple cookies on visitor's web browser?

Yes. The exact limit depends on the browser, [Internet Explorer used to accept 20 but increased this to 50](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941495).

> If so, when user vists the website, which cookies will be delivered to server?

All of them

> And why would a website generate multiple cookies?

So that you don't need to serialise all the data (which could be from unrelated parts of the system) in one cookie.

Answer (score 5):

A cookie is just a single key/value pair, with optional domain, path, expiration and access settings.

Reasons to separate data into separate cookies include:

- Easier to maintain code - various bits of the site that need to store state don't need to interoperate with each other to pack it all into one cookie.
- Easier user management - the end user (you) can see more easily what is stored, and can selectively delete certain cookies.
- Different usages - for example, a cookie holding your session key can be marked `secure; httpOnly;`, while cookies that hold UI preferences can still be accessed via javascript.
- Reduce request size - if some cookies are only used for certain pages, the `path` property can be used so they aren't sent unnecessarily for pages they aren't needed on.

Answer (score 4):

A server can specify any number of cookies and each cookie is specified in its own `Set-Cookie` header.

Each `Set-Cookie` header contains at least the `CookieName=CookieValue` pair, and may contain other `key=value` pairs in addition to either a `secure` or `httpOnly` attribute. These additional pairs and attributes are metadata referring to the actual cookie and cannot be used to set additional cookies.

When a client sends cookies back to a server it combines them all into a single `Cookie` header. This is possible because the client never sends the metadata back, only the cookie name and value.

Consider this HTTP exchange:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.example.com/index.html
Set-Cookie: UserID=12345; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT; domain=.example.com;path=/index.html; httpOnly`
Set-Cookie: SessionID=6478; domain=.example.com;path=/index.html; httpOnly
Set-Cookie: foo=bar

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Cookie: UserID=12345; SessionID=6478; foo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write a program, do you use just one variable? No, right?

Same principle here - cookies are just key/value pairs that your program (server/client) can use.

Comment: You mean one cookies can only save one key/value pair?
I've thought various key/value pairs can be stored in the same cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one domain can generate many cookies.  The maximum number [varies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation) by browser.

Answer (score 0):

-Every site can create any number of cookies it desires. (But it seams this may vary from browser to browser)

-When the user visits the web site all active cookies will be sent.

-It makes sense to have multiple cookies to store separate data. In an extreme comparison compare cookies to classes ;)